# .NET Core DI: Cannot consume scoped service from singleton

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, singleton, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a class like this

```
public class KReport : IReport
{
    private readonly EDevContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
  
    public KReport(EDevContext context, IMapper mapper = null)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
     
    }
    public void GetKReport(int reportId,int page=1)
    {
        string s;
       //some logic here
       if(reportId==1){
             GetKReport(452,2)
       }
    }
}
```

Also in startup I have added a singleton service

```
services.AddSingleton<IKReport, KReport>();
```

But when I execute the application I am getting this error

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: common.IKReport Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> common.KReport': Cannot consume scoped service
> 'Models.EPMO_DevContext' from singleton 'common.IKnReport'.)'

This error wont occur when that recursive call gets commented

Really sorry my understanding of this dependency injection or singleton services are almost 0. So I didnt understand what happens here

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the existence of recursive methods? It sounds like you're trying to construct a short-lived item in a singleton, which the container objects to.

Comment: This error is thrown by ASP.NET Core when you are running in dev mode to warn you about [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are injecting scoped service in KReport.

Use following code in "Startup.cs" file.

```
services.AddScoped<IKReport,KReport>();
```

Comment: Its working now.. Thanks a lot.. but sorry to ask could you please explain the difference..  I a just a beginner with these depedency injection and still not 100% understood what is that exactly..

Comment: The key thing here is as mentioned, the service lifetimes must match in this scenario. `AddScoped` vs `AddSingleton`

Answer (score 3):

You  must  add  EDevContext service before `services.AddSingleton<IKReport, KReport>();`

---

Edit:
From the trace stack, that show  your  class EDevContext  is addScopeService ,you need make the EDevContext  and KReport as the same  lifetimes

Comment: But why does it happens on when the recursive call enabled.. otherwise no error

Comment: @SandeepThomas the problem is because singleton will allow only one instance of method. Recursive call will generate another instance of method which is bound to fail.